# scrollbar should move bottom when searched text matched inside div matched text content which is having scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular9, angular12

I am sharing the example code which is showing a search bar and scrollbar for a div, but searched text should navigate to matched place and scrollbar also should move to bottom when the text is in last line or middle or inside any place.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-textarea-highlight-f5jvj3?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftextarea-highlight%2Ftextarea-highlight.component.ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-textarea-highlight-y7bzte?file=src/app/textarea-highlight/textarea-highlight.component.ts you can like as this

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it (I implemented at least the scollTop-position) the following way:

```
ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
  if (this.$backdrop) {
    this.handleScroll();
  }
}
handleScroll() {
  const markElem = this.$backdrop.nativeElement.querySelector('mark');
  if (markElem) {
    this.$backdrop.nativeElement.scrollTop = markElem.offsetTop;
    this.$textarea.nativeElement.scrollTop = markElem.offsetTop;
  }
}
```

Check this StackBlitz with the changes to your code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-textarea-highlight-7lvdsn?file=src/app/textarea-highlight/textarea-highlight.component.ts